# Do professional choirs run-through on the day?

Tags: choir, rehearsal

I sing in a local community choir and we are having a discussion about whether or not we need to rehearse the music before, during the afternoon of the concert or if we can get away with having the run through at our usual rehearsal slot, a week or so before the concert. Is it important for choirs to rehearse close to the concert?

Comment: In a professional choir, singing is the members' *job*. They get paid for doing it. And a 3-hour rehearsal on the day of the concert isn't going to wreck their delicate little voices! What you do with a community choir depends on your circumstances - there's obviously no sense scheduling a rehearsal that half the choir can't attend.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the circumstances, but if it is a community choir, I assume you don't rehearse more than once or twice every week.  Hence, rehearsing on the day of the concert or the day before will surely not be too much rehearsing.  We used to do this with my community choir in England, especially because normal rehearsals were at the gym of the local primary school, but the concerts were in churches or large church-like city halls we didn't have access to except on the day of the concert and maybe on the day before.  So one last rehearsal just to check out the acoustics, the sitting order, etc definitely makes sense.  Don't worry, you won't strain your voice too much, but make sure that there is plenty of time between the last rehearsal and the concert for everyone to go home and shower and dress up without stress.

Comment: More of a sound check than a rehearsal. Very important to sort out positioning and acoustics, which can't be done until at the venue, but sadly there's often not that opportunity to assemble everyone earlier in the day. +1.